# Webpack - Source maps intermittently providing typescript locations

Tags: typescript, webpack, aws-lambda, bundling-and-minification, source-maps

I've recently taken over an issue with a full stack application which is SSR React and returning the HTML string to the client via a node lambda handler function, all written in Typescript. This app is being bundled using Webpack and I've been tasked with tidying the config up and sorting any issues out. The Webpack has three configurations (believe me when I say it was worse beforehand!): One for the node lambda, one for the client (bundling the js) and one which has shared config for the two of them. Below are the configs for each:

```js
const handlerConfig = {
  target: "node",
  entry: "./src/lambda/index.tsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("dist", "lambda"),
    filename: "index.js",
    library: "index",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
};

const clientConfig = {
  target: "web",
  entry: { client: "./src/client/index.tsx" },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("dist", "assets"),
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
    publicPath: ASSET_PATH,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env.ASSET_PATH": JSON.stringify(ASSET_PATH),
    }),
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({
      fileName: "../manifest.json",
      map: (fileDescriptor) => {
        fileDescriptor.name = fileDescriptor.path;
        return fileDescriptor;
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const commonConfig = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.js$/],
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                "@babel/preset-react",
                "@babel/preset-env",
                "@babel/preset-typescript",
              ],
              plugins: [
                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                ["babel-plugin-styled-components", { ssr: true }],
              ],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
              plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
  },
};


module.exports = [
  merge(commonConfig, handlerConfig),
  merge(commonConfig, clientConfig),
];
```

The issue I'm having is getting the source maps to actually work. More often than not, the source maps are not being used - I'm just getting stack traces with references to the bundle rather than the Typescript used to generate it.

I've tried different source map outputs in the Webpack config, both `ts-loader` and `babel-loader` individually, I've been through the docs for all 3 and I'm just stumped. The only way I can get it to work consistently is by installing and importing the `source-map-support` module in to the handler file, otherwise I have had it providing Typescript references, but this appears to be intermittent and I can not pin down a reason why. `source-map-support` is something we'd like to avoid using if possible, so the question remains as to why I can't get this to work just using the Webpack generated source maps. Is there something glaringly obvious that I've missed?

Adding the tsconfig.json in case this is feeding in to the issue:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": [
      "es5", 
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "transform": "ts-auto-mock/transformer",
        "cacheBetweenTests": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "types": [
    "node",
    "react",
    "jest",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "@types/jest-dom.d.ts",
    "setUpTests.ts",
    "**/*.css",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist*", "dist", "**/dist/*", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a devtool property in clientConfig as well?

Comment: @AndreySmolko Thanks for pointing this out for me; I must have removed this in error. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the issue.